# "No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'Sap.Data.Hana'", Are EF6 migrations supported on SAP HANA database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, hana

I'm trying to configure hana to work with EF6 with migration following the tutorial on the link https://help.sap.com/viewer/1efad1691c1f496b8b580064a6536c2d/Cloud/en-US/ac86b96b98984a7e9b5a3e8194db39ea.html,
but it's always showing this error:
"MigrationsException: No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'Sap.Data.Hana'. Use the SetSqlGenerator method in the target migrations configuration class to register additional SQL generators."

Are EF6 migrations supported on SAP HANA database?

Comment: Did you read following : "To build and run this example, the following assembly references must be added:"

Comment: yes, all added.

Comment: I think the issue is in the NuGet configuation.  Did you see following : To use Microsoft Entity Framework 6.0, you must add it to Microsoft Visual Studio by using Microsoft's NuGet Package Manager.